# How create a radio button in a div tag only with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML tag like below :

```html
<div id="x_G" class="editor-group-x">
     editor-group-x<br />
     <div id="x_L" class="editor-label-x ">
            editor-label-x
     </div>
     <div id="x_F" class="editor-field-x ">
            editor-field-x
     </div>
</div>
```

I must give style with CSS to this tags without any changing in the HTML tags to make a radio button in the div tag with id="x_F", like below picture. The id="x_F" must be converted to a radio button. How can I do this only with CSS ?

[image]

The most important thing is that this job must be done without any adding element to the HTML tags or any direct changing in the HTML tags and all the changes must be done with CSS! Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: This isn't accessible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/What_is_accessibility

Comment: You can't create elements with css.

Comment: Have you looked into JavaScript?

Comment: This will be implementable through CSS, but it won't work logically because you can check neither of them if there are no inputs here around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with CSS, But you can use **javascript** :(Add this to the footer)

```
<script>
var div = document.getElementById('x_F');
div.innerHTML += '<div class="form-group">Add your radio button HTML here</div>';
</script>
```

Or **jQuery** :(Add this after your `jQuery.js`)

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  var div = $('#x_f');
  div.append('<div class="form-group">Add your radio button HTML here</div>');
});
```